# FMX Update control while button is executing

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I need to update FMX UI, while button event is working.
I have something like this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Buttonclick;
begin
Show;
Update('xxxx');
Do something
Update('yyy');
Do something
hide;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.show;
begin
panel1.visible:=true;
end;


procedure TfrmMain.hide;
begin
panel1.visible:=false;
end;


procedure TfrmMain.update(txt:string);
begin
label1.caption:=txt;
end;
```

Of course this is only an example.

My question is: how to update UI while button is executing?

In Berlin, Tokyo everything was fine. In RIO UI is not updating.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. If I understand it I think you want multi threading.

Comment: No, I don't. When user click on button in my app it start operation, that take few seconds. I want to display information about it - progress bar and description about that, what program do. User will wait to end of operation, but he need to know what is going on. But when I try to update UI (eg. label or progress bar) in  my onClick event UI is not changing.

Comment: So, you need to define a thread for that.

Comment: "In Berlin, Tokyo everything was fine" I don't see how it would have been any different. You might want to show an *exact* example that "works fine" on the earlier versions. Regardless, if the "Do domethink" is a long running process, you really should learn how to use threads.

Comment: This can be solved without using threads. The simplest solution is to `Repaint()` the Form after making an update. Another solution is to break up the code into smaller pieces that you execute with `TThread.ForceQueue()` so the main UI loop can run in between each execute.